# Arduino-Pi serial communication - Python code on Pi restarting Arduino sketch?

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I am testing serial communication with an Arduino Uno sending data to a Pi 4b. The Arduino Uno is running a simple sketch that sends an identifier, a random number, and an integer that increments by 1 each time the sketch loops with a 2 second delay:

```
int data1;
int data2 = 0;

void setup(){
 Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
 data1=random(0,50);
 Serial.print("Arduino,");
 Serial.print(data1);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.println(data2++);
 delay(2000);}
```

This Python code reads the data sent by the Arduino as expected:

```
import serial

arduino_port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baudrate=9600, timeout=2.0)

while True:
    data = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
    print(f'Received from Arduino: {data}')
```

and returns the expected sequence:

```
Received from Arduino: Arduino,7,0
Received from Arduino: Arduino,49,1
Received from Arduino: Arduino,23,2
…
```

However, I thought I’d avoid the “while True:” construct and instead use a “once and done” Python program that could be called by cron every 1 minute:

```
import serial

arduino_port = '/dev/ttyACM0'
arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baudrate=9600, timeout=2.0)
data = arduino.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
print(f'Received from Arduino: {data}')
arduino.reset_input_buffer()
```

However, every time the above Python code is run, it ALWAYS returns the same values from the Arduino:

```
Received from Arduino: Arduino,7,0
```

It seems that my “once and done” code on the Pi is restarting the Arduino sketch each time it is run, which is unexpected. The difference in my two versions of Python code is that this line is called once in the version with the `while True` loop but called every time in my "once and done" version:

```
arduino = serial.Serial(arduino_port, baudrate=9600, timeout=2.0)
```

Can this line of code really be restarting the Arduino sketch? Or is there something else in my "once and done" code that is causing the Arduino sketch to restart? Is there a way to construct a "once and done" Python program that does not restart the Arduino sketch each time?

Answer (score 0):

So the Arduinos are designed to reset when the serial port is opened. This enables them to run sketches automatically.  This feature can be disabled - see https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection/